# Can I arrange that other computers only see certain dropbox folders?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I am using Dropbox. I paid for the PRO version and have 1 TB of storage. I want to store most of my files in Dropbox so I can get them backed up. Most of the files are private files (such as vacation photos, my girlfriend, etc). I don't think I should be sharing that with my employees, partners, and well, the whole office.

I wonder what solution I can choose?

They can have their own Dropbox account. The the amount of files I want to share with them may be more than 2 GB.

Comment: This question isn't on topic here at Superuser.  It sounds like you should have 2 separate paid accounts.  Dropbox has specific plans that surround a business I suggest you use that instead of their consumer level service.

Comment: In order to be more specific.  Dropbox from my perspective is primary a web application, your questions isn't dealing with the desktop client specifically, but the file permissions.  Besides in the end your asking for our opinion which doesn't make a very good question.

Comment: Too many questions - can you clarify your question to just one specific question. Whatever [folder you share](https://www.dropbox.com/help/59) will count again their quota. If you share a folder bigger than 2GB, then will not be able to join the shared folder.

Comment: You can not make login your Dropbox to your employee's computer. You can do a selective sync to see the folder you want, but it doesn't stop them from checking the folders on to download the rest of your Dropbox files. Bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

To spend less money, you can try to collaborate with unique Dropbox accounts as long as you observe the 2GB limit for personal accounts. Only one person would need a PRO account or a PERSONAL account with many referrals to boost the total storage. You'd need enough storage to retain the folder contents of everyone you share a folder with (read/write security).

If you want to boost the 2GB limit of each personal account, s/he would need to sign up for bonus offers or refer other people to Dropbox. They can't be referrals to your office as that would be too obvious. When I had my personal Dropbox, I receive 35GB of free storage by heavily promoting Dropbox on my website.

If you want extra features like additional storage or recovering previous versions of files unlimited days, you'll need to use [Dropbox for Business](https://www.dropbox.com/business/try). It costs more, but it also provides storage and features.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: It goes without saying that an answer that points to an online service is useless if the service goes down. Identifying the service ***is*** the essential part of the answer. What do you expect the answerer to add?

Comment: @G-Man Instruction, or a reference, explaining how the linked product can be used for what the user is asking. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) - "Provide context for links"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Sounds like you mean to be referring to [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511) Given that the OP _already_ uses Dropbox, I doubt that he needs a lot of "context" to understand a reference to a different Dropbox service.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect how OP can use a PRO account and get by using Personal accounts on the other Dropbox accounts observing a file storage limit. The Dropbox for Business link was provided if OP needs other features besides what the PRO account provides.

Comment: @G-man Just because the OP understands the context, doesn't mean a link-only answer isn't a crappy answer. It's now 1000% better.